# Problema com UTF-8 na hora de receber os dados Ajax

Tags: ajax, utf-8

Bom dia, verifiquei outros relatos do mesmo problema, porém não consegui usar nenhuma das respostas dadas neles...
Tentei algumas porém não resolve.

Estou usando datatables para mostrar/inserir/editar dados de um formulário, está  funcionando tudo, MENOS a parte de acentuação.
Ele mostra como "Ã£" 
O que acontece no meu é o seguinte, tenho a página index.html 
nela a acentuação está normal, porém os dados recebidos pelo ajax ficam com caracteres bugados.

Já inseri o UTF8 em tudo que é lugar e não resolve, verifiquei e já estou fazendo o encode dos dados, mas não está funcionando, pode estar errado. Sou leigo com ajax, estou usando de metido mesmo, mas consegui até aqui =)

Uso Jquery por causa do datatables, ele tem um charset nos settings do ajax

```
    ajaxSettings: {
    url: ajaxLocation,
    type: "GET",
    isLocal: rlocalProtocol.test( ajaxLocParts[ 1 ] ),
    global: true,
    processData: true,
    async: true,
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
```

Na parte de login também coloquei

```
<?php
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    $server = "localhost";
    $user = "root";
    $password = "**";//
    $bd = "**";

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $password, $bd);
    if (!$conexion){ 
        die('Error de Conexión: ' . mysqli_connect_errno());    
    }   
?>
```

meu index.html pra variar tbm está com o utf-8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_BR">
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>*</title>
```

O que acontece é o seguinte, no meu index.html 
tenho os textbox que quando salvos, eles chamam a função guardar.php

```
var guardar = function(){
    $("form").on("submit", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var frm = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "guardar.php",
            data: frm
        }).done( function( info ){
        console.log( info );        
            var json_info = JSON.parse( info );
            mostrar_mensaje( json_info );
            limpiar_datos();
            listar();
        });
    });
}
```

que redireciona para a página guardar.php
( página completa de como uso).

```
<?php

    include ("conexion.php");

    $idusuario = $_POST["idusuario"];
    $dia = $_POST["dia"];
    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
    $apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
    $dni = $_POST["dni"];
    $ca = $_POST["ca"];
    $pot = $_POST["pot"];
    $pon = $_POST["pon"];
    $bairro = $_POST["bairro"];
    $predio = $_POST["predio"];
    $tecnico = $_POST["tecnico"];
    $entre = $_POST["entre"];
    $motivo = $_POST["motivo"];
    $estado = $_POST["estado"];
    $opcion = $_POST["opcion"];
    $informacion = [];  

    switch ($opcion) {
        case 'registrar':
                if( $dia != "" &&  $nombre != "" && $apellidos != "" && $dni != "" && $ca != "" && $pot != "" && $pon != "" && $bairro != "" && $predio != "" && $predio != "" && $tecnico != "" &&  $entre != "" && $motivo != "" && $estado != ""  ){
                    $existe = existe_usuario($dni, $conexion);
                    if( $existe > 100000 ){ 
                        $informacion["respuesta"] = "EXISTE";
                        echo json_encode($informacion);
                    }else{ 
                        registrar($dia, $nombre, $apellidos, $dni, $ca, $pot, $pon, $bairro, $predio, $tecnico,  $entre, $motivo, $estado, $conexion);
                    }               
                }else{
                    $informacion["respuesta"] = "VAZIO";
                    echo json_encode($informacion);
                }
            break;
        case'modificar':
            modificar($dia, $nombre, $apellidos, $dni, $ca, $pot, $pon, $bairro, $predio, $tecnico, $entre, $motivo, $estado, $idusuario, $conexion);
            break;
        case'eliminiar':
            eliminar($idusuario, $conexion);
            break;
        default:
            $informacion["respuesta"] = "OPCION_VACIA";
            echo json_encode($informacion);
            break;  
    }

        function existe_usuario($dni, $conexion){
        $query = "SELECT idusuario FROM curriculo WHERE dni = '$dni';";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
        $existe_usuario = mysqli_num_rows( $resultado );
        return $existe_usuario;
    }

    function registrar($dia, $nombre, $apellidos, $dni, $ca, $pot, $pon, $bairro, $predio, $tecnico, $entre, $motivo, $estado, $conexion){
        $query = "INSERT INTO curriculo VALUES(0, '$dia', '$nombre', '$apellidos', '$dni', '$ca', '$pot', '$pon', '$bairro', '$predio', '$tecnico',  '$entre', '$motivo', '$estado');";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);       
        verificar_resultado($resultado);
        cerrar($conexion);
    }


    function modificar($dia, $nombre, $apellidos, $dni, $ca, $pot, $pon, $bairro, $predio, $tecnico, $entre, $motivo, $estado, $idusuario, $conexion){ 
    $query= "UPDATE curriculo SET nombre='$nombre', 
    apellidos='$apellidos', 
    dni='$dni',
    ca='$ca',
    pot='$pot',
    pon='$pon',
    bairro='$bairro',
    predio='$predio',
    tecnico='$tecnico',
    dia='$dia',
    entre='$entre',
    motivo='$motivo',
    estado='$estado'
    WHERE idusuario=$idusuario";

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    verificar_resultado( $resultado );
    cerrar( $conexion );
    }

    function eliminar($idusuario, $conexion){
    $query= "UPDATE curriculo SET estado= 0
    WHERE idusuario=$idusuario";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
    verificar_resultado( $resultado );
    cerrar( $conexion );
    }

    function verificar_resultado ( $resultado ) { 
        if ( !$resultado )  $informacion["respuesta"] = "ERROR";
        else    $informacion["respuesta"] = "BIEN";
        echo json_encode ( $informacion );
     }

    function cerrar ( $conexion ) { 
        mysqli_close ( $conexion );
}

?>
```

Como informei, TUDO funciona EXCETO a acentuação, quando escreve ã por exemplo fica Ã£

No meu MYSQL também fica salvo com Ã£. 
porém se eu entro no phpmyadmin e edito o campo para apenas ã, ele fica normal..
Então a dificuldade realmente é no ajax.

Espero que possam me ajudar, 
não necessáriamente precisam me ajudar da forma certa, ou mais complicada...
Pode ser resolvido com gambiarras, ( desde que funcione xD)
E/ou apenas forçando não adicionar o caracter "£" depois da letra acentuada.

Já tentei de quase tudo que eu sabia e não consegui resolver...
Quanto mais procuro mais me perco :(

Já tentei utilizar JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE dentro do meu json_encode.
Ai o código de erro muda de "Ã£" para "Ã±"

Comment: Não adicione "Resolvido" no título. Sei que é uma prática comum em muitos fóruns, mas aqui o funcionamento é diferente: basta você adicionar uma resposta abaixo (no campo "Sua resposta"), e depois [aceite a resposta](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)

Comment: Vale lembra que os arquivos `.html`, `.js` e `.php` também devem estar salvos como UTF8 senão de nada adianta..

Comment: Opa, desculpe não sabia disso, Então, foi Resolvido =)